# Use RENAME in INSTALL(TARGETS ...)

Tags: cmake

I'm fairly new to CMake so please be gentle.

I have a two targets which both need to be called `internal` for further use on runtime. Now, when I call

```
set_target_properties(target1 PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME internal)
install(TARGETS target1 DESTINATION some/where/target1dir)

set_target_properties(target2 PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME internal)
install(TARGETS target2 DESTINATION some/where/target2dir)
```

one of the two targets will be overridden by the other one when invoking cmake, so when executing nmake in the build folder, the same file is copied to `some/where/target1` and `some/where/target2`.

I considered using the `RENAME` option to change the temporary name of the built file to an arbitrary one, but this option is not allowed when using the `TARGETS` keyword.

Do you know how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I worked around this by adding a CMake file to the source directory which renames the files, configuring that file with the target's output name and the rename name, then adding a target property `POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT` which holds the path to the configured cmake file.

Due to a lack of knowledge about variables available to determine certain directories (such as the location of the devel folder) there is still much stuff inside that is hardcoded and the whole workaround seems like overkill and is ugly, so, **if YOU know a better strategy, PLEASE tell me** :)